# How can I classify my text by using unsupervised approaches?

Tags: classification, text-mining, natural-language, unsupervised-learning, sentiment-analysis

I have a corpus of newspaper articles and would like to classify them according to content (words, phrases) that I determine beforehand. The only way to do this that I found so far is by looking at how often my terms appear and then classify into a, b or neither of them. But there must be more sophisticated techniques looking at neighbourhoods, correlations, relative frequencies etc. But I only find these in the context of Naive Bayes, SVM, KNN etc. which require a training set (I'll do that in a later step as well but here I am really interested in explicitly determining classification requirements beforehand).

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you make this more concrete & focused on a narrow question? I suspect people may think this is *too broad* & close it as such.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I am not sure though if I can narrow it down. I am trying to classify a document into "a" or "b" depending on the words used. So far, I've only seen functions that count the appearance of these words and classify according to that. 

I was wondering whether there are other ways to do so.